# Getting average times in mySQL workbench query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a table in mySQL workbench that has several columns and 11 million rows.

One of the columns is a time stamp in the following format:

```
2014-01-01 00:12:54
```

There is another column which I'm doing a group by on.

My query currently looks something like this:

```
SELECT app_type, count(series_id) as 'Num of Series Downloaded' from access_log
WHERE action = 'download' AND org_id != 1
GROUP BY app_type;
```

Which produces a result this:

[image]

What I'd like to do is get the average number of series downloaded (series_id) per month given that I have a time column. Keeping in mind there are 5 years of data and 11 million rows.

Ideally, the result would be formatted something like this:

[image]

What could my query look like to format a result like what I'm aiming to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a basic aggregation query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m') as yyyymm,
       SUM(app_type = 'API') as API,
       SUM(app_type = 'Web') as Web,
       SUM(app_type = 'Excel') as Excel
FROM access_log
WHERE `action` = 'download' AND org_id <> 1
GROUP BY yyyymm;
```

Comment: Possibly because *action* is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). Escape with backticks. Note *timestamp* is also a reserved words. Refrain from using such identifiers.

Comment: Thanks. The column names are above my pay-grade :)